# Why do we need multiprocess programming in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, multiprocessing

Java supports multithread well, and Java also supports multiprocess via Process, ProcessBuilder and Runtime.exec()...

I know clearly the definitions of thread and process,  and the differences between them in os concepts.

But I wonder why and in what situation do we need to use a multiprocess instead of multithread in Java application?

Comment: Threads run in processes...Have a read through [Thread vs Processes](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week11/02.html) and/or [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) and/or [Processes and Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html)

Comment: @NandkumarTekale He might be saying that, but the statement is generally untrue. There's a lot I can't do in a `Thread` that I can do in a `Process`, but I may be mixing my metaphors

Comment: @NandkumarTekale Ah, so hopefully, some of the links might help then, thanks for the clarification ;)

Answer (score 8):

On top of my head, reasons for using `processes` as a complement to `threads` could be

- Robustness, one failing process won't affect another
- Separation. Launching multiple JVM allows running the same classes without worrying about interference (e.g., easier to use non-thread safe libraries)
- Generally to be able to launch external commands (e.g., non-java)
- Thread affinity. In some OS's it *might* provide better cache semantics with processes shared over multiple CPU's rather than threads, especially when considering a thread-shared working set.

Still, in most applications `threading` is the preferred tool for memory reasons, easy to spawn and its (relatively) simple ease of use.

Comment: +1 for `Generally to be able to launch external commands (e.g., non-java)`

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on point 4 a bit because 1) You are talking about the advantages of processes, yet you mention `Thread affinity`. 2) AFAIK you can't set the affinity of a java process or thread programatically (unless you mean by using the task manager or equivalent unix commands for processes?).

Comment: @Tudor, Some OS's doesn't support `Thread Affinity` at all. I also agree on the poor formulation. I wanted to keep the points short, but not for the cost of correctness.

Answer (score 8):

Don't necessarily think of processes as replacements for threads. Processes in java are convenient ways of executing external commands. They aren't really that useful in general parallelism scenarios, as they are cumbersome to start and synchronize.

Another good use of them is to isolate native code (or any other code that you cannot control) that may not terminate or cause stack overflows. If this were to be run inside a thread it could bring the entire process down. Instead, you can spawn a new process and then forcibly kill it without worrying to much about it.

Answer (score 1):

You may need it when synchronization is not an issue, i.e. processes that are not interfering the same data, but you need the outputs of these processes to be collected at the same time, meaning you need to run them in parallel although they are completely different processes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no run-away protection in the JVM.

If you have a thread which will not stop, the only way to forcefully stop it, is to have the operating system kill its JVM.  By having separate processes you can keep the rest of the application running.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, there is no simple answer. Depending on the OS/JVM, Threads and Processes could mean different things and could have different levels of isolation.

**Why have ability to use both??** *Here is an example*

Consider a scenario when you have to use some legacy or thirdparty native (C++) library that is not thread safe (or offers no guarantees). I imagine if you have to streamline your server to utilize high number of processors. a multi-process architecture would be more suitable.

**Isolation**

- If you try to use multi-threading, you risk running into synchronization, dead locks, active locks, etc... issues.
- If you use multi-process architecture, you would guarantee some level of isolation in terms of memory access. You'd be able to

**Error Handling**

- If one of those multi-process components fails, you are more likely able to recover and possibly compensate with another process, instead of bringing the entire JVM down in your starting process. Even though there are way to handle and protect against that, wrapping it in an isolated process will make your life easier.
  *If you ever had to code defensively against some badly written ancient aliens native  library? You'll know what I mean.*

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run a program that is not for JVM but can be run using o/s command line, then you cannot run it as a thread, but only as a process.